# why im getting those signs (look like type) to my header when importing csv table into Dataframe?

Tags: r, import, header

This is my csv table:

[image]

were the header are regular

this is the code:

```
otu <- read.csv("/home/yosdos/Bacteria_Taxonomy.csv",sep="\t",header = T)
```

and this is the result:

[image]

adding a `type` signs

Comment: Try if `utils::read.csv(...)` gives you what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your fast comment, but i'm getting the same result

Comment: @deepseefan how do i do this>

Comment: You mean sharing a link to your file? Put it on your gmail (google drive) and edit the post sharing the link, but I still think something like `out <- utils::read.csv("~/yosdos/Bacteria_Taxonomy.csv",header = TRUE) ` should be able to work if not something along `read.table` or `read.delim`.

Comment: Read https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#What-are-valid-names_003f

Comment: @deepseefan I kind of solve the problem, i ran the line in R outside of jupyter notebook and it didn't display any of that type. and it seems that it does not affect the code. Thank you anyway

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you're trying to change